# why is a window being created without the function being called?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter programming.

**DATA**

I have the following tkinter code:

```
##Program to print something or exit

def say_hi():
    second = Tk()
    Label1 = Label(second,text="HI!")
    Label1.pack()
  
from Tkinter import *
  
root = Tk()
  
r = Button(root,text="QUIT",fg="red",command=quit)
r.pack()
  
b = Button(root,text="Say something",fg="red",bg="black",command=say_hi())
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This gave the following output:

[image]

And on moving the window behind:

[image]

**DOUBT**

Why is the `second` window opening without the function `say_hi()` being called?

**HOW TO SOLVE THIS?**

How can I initiate a new window or a frame in the current window or print a label in the current window so as to print `HI` only after the button is pressed.

I don't want to print it on the console as most of the times it goes unnoticed.

**SPECS**

Visual Python Tkinter IDE 2.6

Comment: You should never create more than once instance of `Tk`; Tkinter isn't designed to be used that way and it will behave in unexpected ways. If you need more than one window, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete `()` after `say_hi`, `say_hi()` will call the function:

```
b = Button(root,text="Say
        something",fg="red",bg="black",command=say_hi) b.pack()
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! It worked after deleting `()` after say_hi.

Comment: Sir, Can you tell me why this happenned?

Comment: The parameter for `command` hast to be the function itself, not the result of the function.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the code:

The `()` will not be there after the `say_hi` in `command`

Modified code is as so:

```
##Program to print something or exit

def say_hi():
    second = Tk()
    Label1 = Label(second,text="HI!")
    Label1.pack()

from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

r = Button(root,text="QUIT",fg="red",command=quit)
r.pack()

b = Button(root,text="Say something",fg="red",bg="black",command=say_hi)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```